# Find multiple strings inside of another string

Tags: java, string, validation, if-statement

Ok so I'm trying to create a simple Email Validation Application.

I'm stuck on a particular bit, where I need to simply find 2 strings in 1 string. I'm tyring to find out whether there is a .com or a .co.uk in the email. So far I have it just to check for .com. I have looked everywhere and cant find a solution. I have tried doing `.indexof(dotCom && dotUK)` but that didn't work.

So simply need it so say ".com" or ".co.uk"

```
     String dotCom = ".com";
     String dotUK = ".co.uk";

     rest = user_email.indexOf( dotCom);

     if (rest== -1){
        System.out.println("Invalid email address. Must contain .com or .co.uk");
     }else{
        System.out.println("Valid email address");
     }
```

Comment: Have you ever thought about using a regex to match a valid email pattern?

Comment: regex will be useful when if he ever expands from just two domains. for this scenario(jsut two domains) regex overcomplicates the issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(mail.contains(".com") || mail.contains(".co.uk")) {
    //is valid
}
```

Don't use `indexOf` for checking existance of substring inside other String, if you don't care about the actual index of it.

If you just want to know if some String contains other String, use `contains` method - it's more straight-forward

as suggested, better would be:

```
if(mail.endsWith(".com") || mail.endsWith(".co.uk")) {
    //is valid
}
```

Comment: assuming these emails are valid they will always end with these so i would suggest endsWith instead of contains

Comment: I tried the contains code you suggested and got the error "int cannot be dereferenced" :s

Comment: @user2131803 post your full code - you must do something really wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex, or a collection of suffixes like this:

```
private static boolean matches(final String      mail,
                               final String ... suffixes)
{
    String match;

    match = null;

    for(final String suffix : suffixes)
    {
        if(mail.endsWith(suffix))
        {
            match = suffix;
            break;
        }
    }

    // or return (match); if you want to know the type.
    return (match != null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, to make work your snippet, that would be

```
if (user_email.indexOf( dotCom) == -1 && user_email.indexOf( dotUK) == -1){
 System.out.println("Invalid email address. Must contain .com or .co.uk");

 }
  else {
    System.out.println("Valid email address");
}
```

on the other hand , you can try [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for a more flexible solution.
hope it helps